# How can I run Postgres locally on two accounts

Tags: postgresql

On my MacBook I have two user profiles. One for work and one for personal use. I develop on both and recently I've wanted to start a local Postgres server but I can't seem to do this. When I try to run `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres` I get this error:

```
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
```

I also can't run it as a super user as it says `pg_ctl: cannot be run as root`

I think this might be because I installed Postgres on my work user profile and even though I can still access the CLI I can't run the Postgres server as I don't have the right permissions on my personal user profile.

Apologies in advance if this is a really obvious error, I am new to development

Comment: Not entirely clear to me, but do you want only Postgres instance and set up separate databases in it? Or do you want to run two entirely different Postgres instances? Also where are you getting Postgres from and how are you installing it?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry I wasn't clear! So I can run and access a Postgres instance from my work user profile on my MacBook as I originally installed it on there directly from Postgres. However when I log into my personal user profile, I don't have permission to run Postgres from there, but I can still use the CLI in the terminal since it recognises my `pg_ctl` and `psql` commands

Comment: See Laurenz Albe's answer. The question still remains, do you want want to create an entirely separate instance of Postgres to develop against from your personal user account, in order not to possibly cause issues with the work instance? Please include your reply as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a PID file present, either the database is running, or you did not shut it down properly, and it crashed.

Anyway, your idea is doomed. Only the user who owns the database files can start the database server.

Perhaps you can use `sudo`:

```sh
sudo -u dbowner pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

But I guess that you misunderstand the principle of client-server software.

You should have the system start PostgreSQL as a service, running as the database owner. Then it is irrelevant as which operating system user you run the client software (unless you are using `peer` authentication in PostgreSQL).

Comment: Thank you! I think I do misunderstand this and would love any guidance to help me understand better. I can start the server using `sudo` but then get a FATAL: role "username" does not exist error when trying to connect to it. I believe this might have to do with how I originally set up the Postgres server and the permissions I consequently set?

Comment: That is a different question.